# purpose is to use R grid.arrange to plot 2 graphs on 1 page and 3 graphs on the next page

Tags: r

Here is the R code I tried to create a pdf with 2 graphs on 1 page and 3 graphs on the next page but it failed telling me to use arrangeGrob. What am I doing wrong in using grid.arrange? Thanks

```
library(ggplot2)
testfunc <- function() {
    pdf("test.pdf", width=8.5, height=11, onefile=TRUE)
    a <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg)) + geom_point()
    b <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg)) + geom_point()
    args.list <- list(a=a, b=b, nrow=1, ncol=2)

    x <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg)) + geom_point()
    y <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg)) + geom_point()
    z <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg)) + geom_point()
    args.list1 <- list(x=x, y=y, z=z, nrow=1, ncol=3)

    #grid.arrange(x, y, z) # 1 graph on each page
    #do.call(grid.arrange, args.list)
    args.list2 <- list(args.list, args.list1)
    do.call(grid.arrange, args.list2)

    dev.off()
}

testfunc()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if all the pages had the same layout you could use `marrangeGrob`, but here you're probably better off looping over a list of layout parameters,

```
library(gridExtra)

lp <- replicate(5, rectGrob(), simplify = FALSE)

layouts <- list(c(lp[1:2], list(nrow=1, ncol=2)), 
                c(lp[3:5], list(nrow=1, ncol=3)))

pdf("multi.pdf")
for(page in seq_along(layouts))
  do.call(grid.arrange, layouts[[page]])
dev.off()

# more terse
pdf("multi.pdf")
invisible(lapply(layouts, function(x) do.call(grid.arrange, x)))
dev.off()
```